# How to store Richtextbox Foramtted COntents in MYSql DB ' Direclty ' using VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, rtf

I have one Field in MYSQL DB. Name is  ' Field1 '.  I can store the Richtextbox text(it contains Bold, Italic, Etc). using the code  ' Richtextbox1.rtf '

But when i am trying to display  using  'Richtextbox1.rtf=dt.rows(0).item(0).tostring ',

It shows  'File Format is not Valid '.

What is the Solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the contents of dt.rows(0).item(0).tostring in debugger? Also, ToString() should be a method, not a property. You missed "()" it seems.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is a VB.Net. In C# only we use string().